# Crystal Reports – Extra columns when exporting (Microsoft Excel (97-2003) format only)

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-export

When exporting a Crystal Report (2016) to excel format, I am getting extra columns in the report.  This does not happen with any other export format.  So empty data columns display in the first 30+ columns.  How can I correct that?

Answer (score 0):

This can get frustrating if the report is too complex, but if you design the report so that no fields overlap and there are no gaps between the fields, then the export should work better.  However, if you have fields and objects in sections where the widths of things in one section differ from the width of things in another section, then you are going to get merged cells and empty cells in your export.

Sometimes its much easier to export the report using one of the (Data Only) Excel export options.  This can help to force the export into single cells without merges and gaps, however, the exported spreadsheet will be unformatted and will require some manual formatting after the export when using this method.